# Simulating mongodb's sorting method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sorting

In mongodb
you get data from the db like this:

```js
const allUsers = await User.find() // returns an array of users
```

You can attach a sort method to the `find()` to sort the data depending on the specified field, 1 for ascending, -1 for descending, like this:

```js
const allSortedUsers = await User.find().sort({ rank: 1 }) // returns an array of users sorted by rank
```

I am trying to understand how this works, and simulate it by my own
But I couldn't so far figure out how they managed to attach a custom `sort()` method to another method that returns an array, or at least how they managed to overwrite the original built-in array `sort()` method so that it accepts an object argument that specifies the property we will use to sort

I tried to simulate the `find()` method, so I made it return a class with a custom `sort()` ... but the problem is that now my `find()` doesn't return an array of data, but an object, so I will have to dig deeper to get the actual array of data..
what I tried:

```js
function find() {
  const data = // finding logic
  return new DataClass(data)
}

class DataClass {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data
  }

  sort(sortByObject) {
    const sortedData = // sorting logic
    return sortedData
  }
}

const users = await find().data // returns the data
const sortedUsers = await find().sort({rank:1}) // returns the sorted data
```

I want to be able to access the data through `find()` and not `find().data`

I also tried another approach, by attaching a custom sort method to the data array in the `find()` .. like this:

```js
function find() {
  const data = // finding logic

  // attaching a sort() function to the data array
  data.sort = function(sortByObject) {
    // sorting logic
  }
  return data
}
```

but this also caused the returned array of data to have something like an extra item that could be iterated over.. which I don't want either .-.

Basically.. I want to simulate mongodb's `find().sort({prop:1})`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Mongoose, I recommend it, as you could do something like

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose')
const objSchema = new Schema({...});

objSchema.methods._sort = function (key, ascending=false) {
  // sorting logic
}

const Obj = Model("Obj" objShcema)

module.exports = Obj
```

And then later you could do,

```
const Obj = require("path/to/export.js")

const found = Obj.findOne({...})
found._sort("some_field", true)
```

In the method, you can apply really any logic, including making separate queries to other documents.